# How to initialise a particles system as a spherical cap?

Tags: javascript, three.js

My Three.js project consists in making a snow fall(with some particles) inside a snowball(a sphereGeometry), a classic Xmas snowball. I have created the particles using `THREE.BufferGeometry()` and I initialised them giving an initial_position for each parameter(x, y, z).
Is there a way to make them visible only inside the sphere? I resolved the problem giving the particles outside the sphere the same colour of the background, but it doesn't work perfectly.

Is there a way to make the particles outside the sphere not visible? Maybe making them transparent.

Otherwise how could I initialise the particles as a spherical cap?
Thanks!

This is how I am initialising particles positions(as a parallelepiped):

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    init_pos_y[i] = 50 + (Math.random()-0.5)*20;
    init_pos_x[i] = (Math.random()-0.5)*100;
    init_pos_z[i] = (Math.random()-0.5)*100;
    acceleration[i] = Math.random()*1;
```

In the Vertex Shader this is how I am making the particles fall and giving them colour(and changing its opacity depending on its position inside or outside the sphere):

```
void main(){

    vec3 p = position; 
    p.x = initial_position_x;
    p.z = initial_position_z;

    if (initial_position_y - time * acceleration > -32.8 + min_level){  
        p.y = initial_position_y - time * acceleration;
    }
    else{
        p.y = -33.8 + min_level;
    }
    float opacity;

    if (p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y + p.z*p.z > 2490.0){ 
        opacity = 0.40;
        vColor = vec4( customColor, opacity );              
    }
    else{
        opacity = 1.0;
        vColor = vec4( customColor2, opacity );
    }

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(p, 1.0);            
    vUv = projectionMatrix * vec4(p, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 3.0*acceleration;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/in-the-orb-shaders/3286?u=prisoner849

Comment: I tried to do generate points randomly inside a circle this way: for(i=0; i<n; i++){

   var ptAngle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
   var ptRadiusSq= Math.random() * 2490.0;

   init_pos_x = Math.sqrt(ptRadiusSq * Math.cos(ptAngle);
   init_pos_y[i] = 50 + (Math.random()-0.5)*20;
   init_pos_z = Math.sqrt(ptRadiusSq * Math.sin(ptAngle);
   }      But it's not working. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to put your points in a formation of cylinder (randomly inside a circle and randomly on height). For that, see function `setInCircle()`.

Then you need to modify the code of shader. I prefer to do it with `.onBeforeCompile()`, thus you can modify necessery parts, keeping all the other functionalities of the material.

In the shader, you change y-value with adding the distance (time * speed), dividing it by 10 (`mod()` function), thus you put it in a cycle to go from top to bottom in range of 5 to -5.

The last thing is to check if the length of the given transformed vector is less or equal to given radius, passing the result in a varying to the fragment shader, where you discard a pixel if the result if less than 0.5.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var pts = [];
var radius = 5;
var pointsCount = 5000;

for (i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
  let v2 = setInCircle().multiplyScalar(radius);
  let v3 = new THREE.Vector3(v2.x, THREE.Math.randFloat(-radius, radius), v2.y);
  pts.push(v3);
}

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);
var uniforms = {
  speed: {
    value: 1
  },
  time: {
    value: 0
  },
  radius: {
    value: radius
  }
}
var mat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: "magenta",
  size: 0.05
});
mat.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
  shader.uniforms.speed = uniforms.speed;
  shader.uniforms.time = uniforms.time;
  shader.uniforms.radius = uniforms.radius;
  shader.vertexShader = `
    uniform float speed;
    uniform float time;
    uniform float radius;
    varying float vVisible;
  ` + shader.vertexShader;
  //console.log(shader.vertexShader);
  shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    `#include <begin_vertex>`,
    `#include <begin_vertex>
    transformed.y = mod((transformed.y - speed * time) - 5., 10.) - 5.;
    vVisible = length(transformed) <= radius ? 1.: 0.;
  `
  );
  shader.fragmentShader = `
    varying float vVisible;
  ` + shader.fragmentShader;
  console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
    `void main() {`,
    `void main() {
      if (vVisible < 0.5) discard;
    `
  );

}
var points = new THREE.Points(geom, mat);
scene.add(points);

function setInCircle() {
  let v = new THREE.Vector2();
  v.set(
    THREE.Math.randFloat(-1, 1),
    THREE.Math.randFloat(-1, 1)
  )
  return v.length() <= 1 ? v : setInCircle();
}

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  uniforms.time.value = clock.getElapsedTime();
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```